# Does "contest on acquisition" make sense?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Does the phrase "contest on acquisition" make sense in the following sentence:

> This contest on acquisition has not only made no life-enjoyments but
>   also has left us to become deeply desperate.

The context argues that people feel they are in a competition these days to acquire more possessions and that has caused them not to enjoy their lives and become more desperate.

Comment: "made no life-enjoyments" isn't idiomatic; "left us to become" is redundant.  But you didn't ask about those parts of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, but your comment was so valuable

Comment: The idiomatic phrase is "keeping up with the Joneses" and means the competition with one's neighbors to always have as much or more than they do:  "This 'keeping up with the Joneses' has not only made life no fun, but has also left us bankrupt and desperate."

Comment: I'd tend to word this as "The race to acquire has made life no more enjoyable, (and) yet no less desperate."

Comment: I'd call it gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is a versatile preposition.  It can mean "on the topic of":

> The ambassador spoke for two hours **on** international trade agreements.

But it can also mean "at commencement":

> **On** hearing that the ambassador's speech would be about trade
>   agreements, he immediately fell asleep.

These two meanings clash in the phrase "contest on acquisition."  It can mean either a contest in which you try to accumulate possessions or a contest that starts when when you actually make an acquisition.  It would be better to say, "This contest for acquisition."

Comment: I agree with deadrat that your sentence is awkward (in addition to your phrase). How about __As a society, our desire to accumulate wealth has left us spiritually bereft and actually hinders our ability to enjoy life.__ As an aside, this is a tough conclusion to make since the major alternative to capitalism is communism. You will have to offer an explanation for a better way to pursue happiness or give examples of communal living arrangements that promote joy and contentment without the acquisition of wealth. Convents, kibbutz, the Amish ...